# Cannot crop image using react-image-crop

Tags: reactjs, jsx, image-uploading, crop

I trying to crop image using react-image-crop (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop/v/6.0.7). Actually I cannot move cropped area or stretch it. I also use there React DragZone to upload image. Could you explain what I'm doing wrong and what could be the problem ? React-image-crop css is also imported. Can anybody help?

[image: This cropped area do not move and do not resizeble]

```
import React, {useCallback} from 'react'
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone'
import ReactCrop from 'react-image-crop'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import 'react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css';
import "../Styles/ImageUpload.css"

function ImageUpload(files, addFile) {

  const crop = {
    disabled: false,
    locked: false,
    unit: 'px', // default, can be 'px' or '%'
    x: 130,
    y: 50,
    width: 200,
    height: 200
  }

  const onCrop = (image, pixelCrop, fileName) => { 
  }

  const onImageLoaded = (image) => {
  }

  const onCropComplete = async crop => {
  }

  const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
    if (Object.keys(rejectedFiles).length !== 0) {
    }
    else {
      files.addFile(acceptedFiles);

      let popupBody = document.getElementsByClassName("popup-container")[0];
      popupBody.innerHTML = "";
      let cropElement = (<ReactCrop src = {URL.createObjectURL(acceptedFiles[0])} crop={crop} 
      onImageLoaded={onImageLoaded}
      onComplete={onCropComplete}
      onChange={onCrop} />);

      ReactDOM.render(cropElement, popupBody);

  }, [])

  const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({onDrop, noKeyboard: true})

  return (
    <div className = "popup-container">
    <p>Upload new photo</p>
    {  
      (() => {
        if (files.length == undefined) {          
          return (<div>
            <input className = "testinput" {...getInputProps()} />
            <div className = "popup-body" {...getRootProps()}> 
              <img src={require("../Resources/upload-image.png")} className = "image-upload-img"/>                        
              <p style = {{'font-family':'Verdana'}}>Chouse a <b className = "file-manualy- 
              upload">file</b> or drag it here</p>      
            </div> </div>)
        } 
        else {
        }
    })()}

    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also face the same issue, Here you are trying to add **disabled, locked** in crop property but it is invalid because crop property takes following values:

```
{
  unit: 'px', // default, can be 'px' or '%'
  x: 130,
  y: 50,
  width: 200,
  height: 200
}
```

To solve this add disabled, locked as a props in  component instead of crop property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure sure why you would do a `ReactDom.render` from within the function. It seems to be counter to what React is and guessing that the library isn't binding events properly.

I would suggest, after the user drops the image, you load the image using a file reader and set it as state and change the display to show the `<ReactCrop src=={this.state.img} />`. The `crop` also needs to be in a state, so that when it changes, it updates the crop rectangle.

Here's a working example from the creator himself: https://codesandbox.io/s/72py4jlll6